# SQL - How to do a left join with a condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements, left-join

I have two tables: rais.rais_vinculo and code.division

In **rais_vinculo** I have the field "**CODE**" with values from 1000 to 99999.

In **division** I have the field "**code**" with values from 1 to 99 and the field "description".

I want to do a `left join()` to put the field "description" with "CODE" by matching the first digits. Example: if "9000" or "9999" match with "9" and "99999" or "99211" match with "99"

What I have:

> code | description
>
> 1    | Agro
>
> ...  | ...
>
> 99   | Others

And

> CODE
>
> 1000
>
> ....
>
> 99999

What I want:

> CODE | description_code
>
> 1000    | Agro
>
> ...  | ...
>
> 9000    | Industry
>
> 9999 | Industry
>
> ...  | ...
>
> 10000   | Commerce
>
> ...  | ...
>
> 999999   | Others

What I already have:

```
UPDATE rais.rais_vinculo
SET description_code = division.description
FROM code.division WHERE CODE = code
```

Comment: You might consider prettifying the code you post on Stackoverflow, for example instead of `CNAE.2.0.Classe` you might call it `x`. It's way more readable. (Or at least in english)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you want a `left join`?  I think this is sufficient:

```
update rais.rais_vinculo rv
    set descricao_cnae_divisao = d.descricao
    from cnae.divisao d
    where floor("CNAE.2.0.Classe" / 1000) = cnae;
```

Comment: Why didn't I think it?  Thanks a lot !